# Exercise 1.3.31 from Leinster

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, category-theory, order-theory

Here's an exercise from Leinster's Basic Category Theory:

[image]

The question that arose are:

(1) I believe the definition of $\mathbf{Ord}$ on maps in $\mathscr B$ is is follows. Given a bijection of finite sets $f:B\to B'$, assign to it the function $\mathbf{Ord}(f):\mathbf{Ord}(B)\to\mathbf{Ord}(B')$ defined as follows. Every element of $\mathbf{Ord}(B)$ is a subset of $B\times B$. For every $(b,\hat b)$ in that subset, assign to it $(f(b),f(\hat b))$. Thus obtained set of pairs is then the image of the element of $\mathbf{Ord}(B)$ we started with under $\mathbf{Ord}(f)$. It is clear that $\mathbf{Ord}(f)$ is a functor as long as the set consisting of all pairs $(f(b),f(\hat b))$ lies in $\mathbf{Ord}(B')$. But it's not obvious to me that this is so. That is, why does the set of all pairs $(f(b),f(\hat b))$ for all $(b,\hat b)$ from the original element of $\mathbf{Ord}(B)$ satisfy all requirements of a total order?

(2) I don't understand the hint "consider identity permutations". Suppose there is a natural transformation $\alpha=(\alpha_B:\mathbf{Sym}(B)\to\mathbf{Ord}(B))_{B\in\mathscr B}$. Let $f:B\to B'$ be an arrow. Naturality says that $$\alpha_{B'}\circ Sym(F)=Ord(f)\circ \alpha_B$$
When applied to the id permutation, this translates to
$$\alpha_{B'}(id)=Ord(f)(\alpha_B(id))$$I don't see any way to simplify this further, nor do I see any contradiction.

(3) If one uses that "a total order on a finite set amounts to a way of placing its elements in sequence", then it is clear that $Sym(X)$ has $n!$ elements where $|X|=n$. But the above quote is very informal. How to prove that $Sym(X)$ has $n!$ elements based only on formal definitions?

Comment: Define a function that regards a bijection as a permutation, and viceversa. The point of the exercise is that there is a bijection between the two sets, but no one can be made into the component of a natural transformation: this is because on the last equation you wrote, one side does not contain $f$, the other does. [not exactly: it's a willingly imprecise hint. Work on this]

Answer (score 1):

For (1), it is more intuitive to think of a total order $\leq$ in terms of $x\leq y$. Thus you are defining $f(x)\leq f(y)$ if and only if $x \leq y$. From this rephrasing, it's clear that $B'$ is totally ordered by the proposed relation.

(2) Well, it's only a hint, you still have to figure something out yourself. For a bigger hint, try letting $B=B'$.

(3) I discourage you from worrying about this. Math involves formality, but there's rarely any point in looking for a more formal proof of something you understand perfectly. Your argument fleshes out to the usual: there are $n$ choices for the least element, $n-1$ choices for the second least, and so on. No need to formalize further, although you could certainly give an inductive proof if you really want.

Comment: Setting $B=B'$ was the first thing I tried doing (I thought the Leinster's hint is to take $f=id:B\to B$). But I still don't see what it gives. With $f=id$, the naturality condition applied to $\sigma$ just gives $\alpha_B(\sigma)=\alpha_B(\sigma)$.

Comment: I didn't say let $f=\mathrm{id_B}$! The identity permutation is to be viewed as an *element* of $\mathrm{Sym}(B)$.

Comment: Then for any $f:B\to B$, we have $Ord(f)(\alpha_B(id))=\alpha_B(id)$. As far as I understand, this should imply $f=id$. If this is right, this only says that for any $B$, there are no arrows $B\to B$ other than $id:B\to B$. Does this prove that no natural transformation can exist since there are non-id functions of sets $B\to B$?

Comment: @user634426 That's getting the idea, yes. To make things a bit more precise, note that $\mathrm{Ord}(f)$ is a bijection $\mathrm{Ord}(B)\to \mathrm{Ord}(B)$. For which $f$ does this bijection leave any elements fixed? Not very many...And then, almost right in your last sentence-the point is that every set with more than one element admits a nontrivial *bijection* to itself, not just a nontrivial *function*. Remember our domain is finite sets and *isomorphisms*, not the usual category of finite sets, on which these functors are not even defined.

Comment: "For which $f$ does this bijection leave any elements fixed? Not very many..." If this should imply that $f=id$, then I don't see how: we have only one fixed point, there are many bijections from a set with e.g. 20 elements which have one fixed point. The argument I had in mind is one in terms of subsets of $B^2$. Both $\alpha_B(id)$ and $Ord(\alpha_B(id))$ should be the same subset of $B^2$, and the latter is obtained from the former by applying $f$ to each element of each ordered pair in $\alpha_B(id)$. From here I concluded that $f=id$.

Comment: @user634426 Looks right to me. My point was that $\mathrm{Ord}(f)$ fixes no elements whatsoever unless $f=\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: I'm not convinced by my argument. For example, we may consider the set $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and the bijection $f:X\to X$  given by $a\mapsto c,b\mapsto d,c\mapsto a, d\mapsto b$. Then the image of $\{(a,b),(c,d)\}\subset X^2$ is again $\{(a,b),(c,d)\}$ but $f$ is not the identity. Of course $\{(a,b),(c,d)\}$ is not a total order, but a priori it's not clear (to me) that such a thing cannot happen with a total order (or that $Ord(f)$ cannot have a fixed point).

Comment: Oops, in my example $Ord(f)$ doesn't have a fixed point, but still my argument doesn't convince me.

Comment: @user634426 OK, try a proof by induction, using that a total order on a set induces an order on that set with the least element removed