# Functors from category of finite sets and bijections to the category of sets

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

> **[Tom Leinster, Exercise 1.3.31]** A permutation of a set $X$ is a bijection $X \rightarrow X$. Write **Sym**$(X)$ for the set of permutations of $X$. A total order on a set $X$ is an order $\leq$ such that for all $x, y \in X$, either $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$; so a total order on a finite set amounts to a way of placing its elements in sequence. Write **Ord**$(X)$ for the set of total orders on $X$. Let $\mathscr{B}$ denote the category of finite sets and bijections.
> (a) Give a definition of **Sym** on maps in $\mathscr{B}$ in such a way that **Sym** becomes a functor $\mathscr{B} \rightarrow$  **Set**. Do the same for **Ord**. Both your definitions should be canonical (no arbitrary choices).
> (b) Show that there is no natural transformation **Sym** $\rightarrow$ **Ord**. (Hint: consider identity permutations.)
> (c) For an $n$-element set $X$, how many elements do the sets **Sym**$(X)$ and **Ord**$(X)$ have?
> Conclude that **Sym**$(X) \cong Ord(X)$ for all $X \in \mathscr{B}$, but not naturally in $X \in \mathscr{B}$.
> (The moral is that for each finite set $X$, there are exactly as many permutations of $X$ as there are total orders on $X$, but there is no natural way of matching them up.)

I am aware of the [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353370/exercise-1-3-31-from-leinster), but I solved it in this way...

Since $\mathscr{B}$ is category of finite sets and bijections, so if $X, Y \in \mathscr{B}$ such that there is a map $ f: X \rightarrow Y$, since $f$ is a bijection and $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets, hence $|X| = |Y|$. So **Sym**$(X)$ $=$ **Sym**$(Y)$ $\in$ **Set**, where **Set** is the category of sets. Hence, I think $(?)$ that **Sym**$(f)$ is nothing but identity morphism on **Sym**$(X)$. But I can't understand what **Ord**$(f)$ should be. I know that $|$ **Ord** $(X)$ $|$ $=$ $n!$, if $|X| = n$, but I don't know how to proceed. Also, I don't understand how to solve the part (b), even using the hint.

It will be beneficial if someone helps me to solve the problem and clarify my doubts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $|X|=|Y|$ does not imply $\text{Sym}(X)=\text{Sym}(Y)$ (although it does imply $|\text{Sym}(X)|=|\text{Sym}(Y)|$).

Comment: @AndreasBlass Why so? If $|X| = |Y| = n$, then Sym$(X)$ = Sym$(Y)$ $= S_n$, isn't it?

Comment: No. Sym($X$), Sym($Y$), and $S_n$ are isomorphic but not equal. They are sets of permutations of $X$, $Y$ and $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ respectively, and those permutations can be quite different functions.